# Removing x-goog headers from Google Cloud Storage responses

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

The response headers for an object stored in a Google Cloud Storage bucket include Google-specific headers like `x-guploader-uploadid`, `x-goog-generation`, and `x-goog-storage-class`. The GCP console doesn't appear to have a way to disable these headers. Is there some other way built into GCS to remove the Google response headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two APIs: XML and JSON.

AFAIK only the XML API provides those extension headers. The JSON API does not. You cannot control which headers are returned in HTTP responses. Some of those headers can be used in request header match conditions.

The headers are documented here:

- [XML API HTTP headers and query string parameters](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers#headers)
- [JSON Standard Query Parameters](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/parameters#headers)